# Find files whose size is less than 10 MB

Tags: find

I need to find the files in my current directory whose size is less than or equal to 10 MB. `ls -lh` gives me the file size of each file, but I'm not sure how to find the files whose size are less than or equal to 10 MB.

```
host@407d:t1_snapshot$ ls -lth
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Should be

```
find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -size -10M
```

That is find:

- this directory only
- type is a file
- size less than 10 megs

Answer (score 0):

Well, the *h* switch will make this very tough, because the 'human-readable format' it specifies gives you files in G (for gigabyte) when over 1023MB, in M (for megabyte) when over 1023KB and in KB when over 1023 bytes.

`ls -lsr > size && nano size`
is a better command to use, because

the size is displayed consistently and
it will soft files by size for you, largest first, plus
it will output the result to the file 'size', and
show you the result in the text editor nano.

Then, scroll up from the top of 'size' once the command completes and find the small files in nano.

--

Or, you can use *find*  instead of *ls*  , with

`find  ~ -type -a  -size '-10M' -exec ls -lah '{}' ';'`

Answer (score 0):

Open your terminal and type as

```
du -H --min-depth=1 /home/username
```

that will sort the usage min to max so that you can see what are less then < 10 MB size.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `find` command e.g. to find any plain files smaller than 10MB in the current directory and give a long listing of them similar to `ls -l`

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -size -10M  -type f -ls
```

If you want to descend into subdirectories as well, remove the `-maxdepth 1`